# Create a proper DataFrame in python after a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following task; I have a dataframe in python with N columns. For each pair of column, I want to create one single column with the ratio between the values of the second column and the previous one. I think I found the proper way to do it but I can't find the way to display the result into a new Dataframe. My input dataframe looks like this:

```
Name  1A  1B  2A  2B  3A  3B  536A  536B ...
name1 x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8 
name2 ........
namN  ........
```

So for each pair, let's take the first one for example, I want to create a column defined by 1B/1A, than one defined by 2B/2A ecc. 
This is the code that I tried:

```
l = []
for i in np.arange(0,536,2):
    dic1={}
    dic1[i+1] = df.iloc[:,i]/df.iloc[:,i+1]
    l.append(dic1)
```

But after I tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(l)
```

I got a confused dataframe in which values of multiple columns are stored in the same cell. I report here the result.

[image]

I guess that is because I did not define the name of the columns that I created with the ratio, but I can't figure it out.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: it looks like your cells contain the whole row, while the rest of the cells in that row are empty. Lemme see if i can help.

Answer (score 1):

Singular implementation:

```
df['1B/1A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['1B']/x['1A'], axis=1)
```

What's happening here:

- .apply() function lets you apply a method over your whole series/dataframe.
- lambda x: lets you iterate over each row, and here you can access each column by referencing it.

or even simpler:

```
df['1B/1A'] = df['1B'] / df['1A']
```

> UPDATE: Generic Implementation

```
cols = df.columns
a_cols = [col for col in cols if 'A' in col]
b_cols = [col for col in cols if 'B' in col]
for a, b in zip(a_cols, b_cols):
   df[b+'/'+a] = df[b] / df[a]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no need for `apply`. Just do `df['1B/1A'] = df['1B'] / df['1A']`. Same goes for `df['2B/2A']`

Comment: @RamshaSiddiqui Siddiqui thank you, but it gives me the following error: `'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Comment: fixed. try now!

Comment: @RamshaSiddiqui Thank you! I also found another way:                                     
   `for i in np.arange(0,536,2):
           df[i+1] = df.iloc[:,i]/luo.iloc[:,i+1]`